# What would be the possible issue in the JDBC connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was trying to connect mysql database in Eclipse JEE. I tried creating the connection using the database perspective. Database connection->new->mysql. When I was checking the connection it gives be connection failure with these details

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'database'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1748)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2506)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: what is the connection string ?

Comment: Please use code formatting so we aren't looking at one giant blob.

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'database'

Seems that you forgot to change the name of your database.

Review your connection String:

```
java:mysql://<server>:<port>/<database_name>
                             ^ change this for a real database in your MySQL server
```